# Mathematica 10 ListPointPlot3D PlotTheme bug?

Tags: plotting, bugs, plot-themes

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.3 or earlier**

---

I am using *Mathematica* 10 to generate a 3D point plot of a crystal lattice structure. I wanted to set the `PlotTheme` to `"Classic"`, but by accident I set it to `"Monochrome"` instead. This turns all the points to black spheres. When I tried to reset the `PlotTheme` to `"Classic"`, but the plot points remain black spheres. I have tried restarting *Mathematica*, turning kernel on/off , all without success. All the other `PlotTheme`s seem to be working though.

Is this a bug? Any suggestion on how to overcome this?

edit: I am changing the question to how to obtain v9 colored spheres in v10 using `ListPointPlot3D`. My code is:

```
u1 = {0, 1, 0};
u2 = {Sqrt[3]/2, -(1/2), 0};
u3 = {0, 0, 1};
ListPointPlot3D[{
  Partition[Flatten[Table[l u1 + p u2 + q u3, {l, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}, {q, -3, 3}]], 3]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03], PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

this produces a bunch of black spheres for me, I just want the classic v9 colored spheres :(

Comment: Can you give the code you used to cause this problem to see if others can reproduce it?

Comment: Perhaps the points are supposed to be black spheres in the "Classic" plot theme?

Comment: No, the classic theme spheres are blue and purplish spheres

Comment: this is a simplified version of my code but it illustrates the problem. i have a hexagonal lattice defined by lattice vectors u1, u2, and u3 given below:

u1 = {0, 1, 0};
u2 = {Sqrt[3]/2, -(1/2), 0};
u3 = {0, 0, 1};

ListPointPlot3D[
 Partition[
  Flatten[Table[
    l u1 + p u2 + q u3, {l, -3,
      3}, {p, -3, 3}, {q, -3, 3}]], 3], 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]

this generates the lattice with all the lattice points being black spheres. But when i switch to PlotTheme->"Classic" the lattice points stay as black spheres :( I just want the classic look.

Comment: @user64620  Without using "Monochrome", "Classic" produces black for me.  So I see no relation between them.  This produces an error: `ListPointPlot3D[Partition[Flatten[Table[l u1 + p u2 + q u3, {l, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}, {q, -3, 3}]], 3], PlotTheme -> "Classic"]`.  V10.0.1, Mac OSX 10.9.5.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: thank you michael. i actually wrote the code using mathematica 9, where the default (classic) output are blue and purplish spheres. I just double checked the code, without specifying plottheme, the spheres are not black, but are the default bluish color for v10. You can see it better using PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03]. with plottheme -> monochrome, the spheres turns black. I also get an error with classic... this is very concerning and i don't know why. i guess my question now would just be how to produce the v9 colored spheres in v10 for listpointplot3d.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both options `PlotTheme -> None` and `PlotTheme -> "Classic"` don't give the expected coloring for the points. However, you can set their color explicitly using `PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.03], ColorData[1][1]]`:

```
ListPointPlot3D[
  Partition[Flatten[Table[l u1 + p u2 + q u3, {l, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}, {q, -3, 3}]], 3], 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.03], ColorData[1][1]]]
```

> [image: LPP3D]

---

## Additional Observation:

Setting the `PlotTheme` to `"Classic"` or `None` without specifying a `PlotStyle`:

```
ListPointPlot3D[
  Partition[Flatten[Table[l u1 + p u2 + q u3, {l, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}, {q, -3, 3}]], 3], 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

or

```
ListPointPlot3D[
      Partition[Flatten[Table[l u1 + p u2 + q u3, {l, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}, {q, -3, 3}]], 3], 
      PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotTheme -> None]
```

results in an error message

> ```
> MapThread::mptd: Object Automatic at position {2, 2} in MapThread[Function[{Graphics`ListPointPlot3DDump`d$,Charting`s$},If[Last[Graphics`ListPointPlot3DDump`d$]===None,<<1>>,If[Head[First[<<1>>]]===Point&&FreeQ[Last[Graphics`ListPointPlot3DDump`d$],#1],{Charting`s$,Prepend[Last[<<31>>],(Point[<<1>>]&)[<<1>>]]},{Charting`s$,ReleaseHold[(<<1>>&)/@First[<<1>>]]}]]],<<1>>] has only 0 of required 1 dimensions. >>
> ```

and no plotted points. 
This is not the case for all the other base themes, indicating that the behavior observed by the OP is indeed a bug in `ListPointPlot3D`.

Comment: nicely done! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be the setting `"DefaultPlotStyle" -> Automatic` in the `Method` option in the plot theme:

```
Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Classic", ListPointPlot3D]
(*
  {AxesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[0.2]], 
   BaseStyle -> Automatic, FaceGridsStyle -> Automatic, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times"}, 
   Method -> {
     <omitted>,
     "DefaultPlotStyle" -> Automatic, 
     <omitted>}}
*)
```

Evidently from the error message one gets from `ListPointPlot3D[data, PlotTheme -> "Classic"]`, which indicates `MapThread` is called on `Automatic`, the setting `Automatic` should be or have been replaced by a `List` of styles.  it seems like a simple bug to fix.  Certainly we can do it at on the user side by replacing `Automatic` with the list of styles for `ListPlot`:

```
classicListPointPlot3D[data_, opts : OptionsPattern[ListPointPlot3D]] :=
  With[{defaultstyles = 
     "DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Classic", ListPlot])},
   ListPointPlot3D[data, opts, 
    Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Classic", ListPointPlot3D] /. 
     HoldPattern["DefaultPlotStyle" -> _] -> ("DefaultPlotStyle" -> defaultstyles)]
   ];

classicListPointPlot3D[
 GatherBy[
  Flatten[
   Table[l u1 + p u2 + q u3, {l, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}, {q, -3, 3}], 2],
  Last],
 PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.025], PointSize[0.04]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

In *Mathematica* v10.3 this bug is fixed. Also [setting the `PlotTheme` to `"Classic"` or `None` without specifying a `PlotStyle`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69258/18476) now works as expected.

```
$Version
```

$\ $`"10.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)"`

```
u1 = {0, 1, 0};
u2 = {Sqrt[3]/2, -(1/2), 0};
u3 = {0, 0, 1};
ListPointPlot3D[{Partition[
   Flatten[Table[l u1 + p u2 + q u3, {l, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}, {q, -3, 3}]], 3]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.03], PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

[image]

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Partition[
  Flatten[Table[l u1 + p u2 + q u3, {l, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}, {q, -3, 3}]], 3], 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotTheme -> "Classic"]
```

[image]

```
ListPointPlot3D[
 Partition[
  Flatten[Table[l u1 + p u2 + q u3, {l, -3, 3}, {p, -3, 3}, {q, -3, 3}]], 3], 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotTheme -> None]
```

[image]