# globally turn off plot markers for `ListLinePlot` under "Monochrome" theme

Tags: plotting, graphics

Choosing the "Monochrome" theme surprisingly (bug?) adds plot markers to `ListLinePlot`.  I would like to turn this off globally.  (Specifically, I want to set `$PlotTheme` to "Monochrome" but have each `ListLinePlot` with no plot markers -- unless explicitly requested for an individual plot.)

I am looking for a global setting, not plot by plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following global settings:

```
$PlotTheme = "Monochrome";
SetOptions[ListLinePlot, Mesh -> 0];
```

Now the plot markers are gone:

```
ListLinePlot[Range@10]
```

[image]

To restore the default settings:

```
$PlotTheme = Automatic;
SetOptions[ListLinePlot, Mesh -> None];
```

Comment: I'm wondering why the right choice is `Mesh->0` instead of `PlotMarkers->None`.  (I see that your suggestion works; I don't understand why the alternative does not.)

Comment: It's "unusual behaviour" as rcollyer already remarked

Comment: Aha; at least surprising and possibly (?) buggy.  Thanks!

Comment: In version 12, this no longer works.

Answer (score 7):

It is definitely not a bug. There is only so much that you can do with dashing, so plot markers are useful for making monochrome curves distinguishable.

As rcollyer points out in a comment, the most straightforward way to get rid of the plot markers is to add that option along with `PlotTheme`:

```
ListLinePlot[{
  Prime[Range[10]],
  Fibonacci[Range[10]],
  Range[10]
  }, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", PlotMarkers -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Another option would be to [create your own plot theme](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54545/is-it-possible-to-define-a-new-plottheme) and use the setting given by Eldo to set the default plot theme to this.

As MichaelE2 showed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/69268/731), and others elsewhere, there is a function called `` Charting`ResolvePlotTheme `` that will tell you exactly what the settings for a particular plot theme are.

```
style = Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Monochrome", ListLinePlot];
ListLinePlot[{
  Prime[Range[10]],
  Fibonacci[Range[10]],
  Range[10]
  }, Sequence @@ style]
```

[image: Mathemetica graphics]

We can override options by prepending changes to `style`:

```
ListLinePlot[{
  Prime[Range[10]],
  Fibonacci[Range[10]],
  Range[10]
  }, Sequence @@ Prepend[style, PlotMarkers -> None]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In other words, `Prepend[style, PlotMarkers -> None]` could be made its own plot theme and be used as the default plot theme.

Comment: Instead of pulling the entire set of theme options using ``Charting`ResolvePlotTheme`` why don't you just use `PlotMarkers -> None` plus the theme?

Comment: @rcollyer Thank you, good point. I reframed the answer and included this.

Comment: I think you left off in the middle of the edit ... :) Per eldo's answer, you could also use `SetOptions` to set `PlotMarkers -> None` which would have the same effect.

Comment: @rcollyer That's what the half-done paragraph was going to be about, but then it turned out that setting `PlotMarkers -> None` has no effect, which is probably why Eldo didn't do that. I removed that paragraph now.

Comment: Ah, good point. I don't know if that would be considered a bug; it's definitely unusual behavior, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the option `MeshStyle -> None`:

```
SetOptions[ListLinePlot, MeshStyle -> None];
ListLinePlot[{Prime[Range[10]], Fibonacci[Range[10]], Range[10]}, 
   PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, create a custom `PlotTheme` modifying the `"Monochrome"` theme by removing the `PlotMarkers` following the method in [this answer by Mr.Wizard's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54545/is-it-possible-to-define-a-new-plottheme):

```
Themes`AddThemeRules["myTheme",
  DeleteCases[Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Monochrome", ListLinePlot], 
   Rule[PlotMarkers, _]]];

ListLinePlot[{ Prime[Range[10]], Fibonacci[Range[10]], Range[10]}, 
 PlotTheme -> "myTheme"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Aw, gosh, I was just going to do the ``DeleteCases[]`` plot theme thing...+1

Comment: @Michael, it took me a while to find Mr.Wizard's post to get this in:) Thank you for the vote.

Comment: Using `SetOptions` to change the `MeshStyle` no longer works. (Mma12 on Win 10.)